# Why I am getting this Resharper warning - does not override 'Object.Equals(object o) and 'Object.GetHashcode()'

Tags: c#, resharper, overloading

I have the following class:

```
public class CalculateToValue
{
    public CalculateToValue(string normalValue)
    {
        NormalValue = normalValue;
    }

    public string NormalValue { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(string other)
    {
        return NormalValue.Equals(other);
    }

    public bool Equals(CalculateToMax other)
    {
        return NormalValue.Equals(Enum.GetName(typeof(CalculateToMax),
    other));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(CalculateToValue a, CalculateToMax b)
    {
        if (((object) a == null) || ((object) b == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(CalculateToValue a, CalculateToMax b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
  }
```

It works all fine. But it shows a resharper warning on the class. It says -

calculate value defines operator `==` or operator `!=` but does not override `Object.Equals(object o)` and `Object.GetHashcode()`

The warning gets fix if I generate the code via resharper.

```
   protected bool Equals(CalculateToValue other)
    {
        return string.Equals(NormalValue, other.NormalValue);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((CalculateToValue) obj);
    }
```

Now since this class is a legacy class, I am not sure if the above resharper generated code is fine.

Can someone please explain me why I get this warning?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470059/warning-overrides-object-equalsobject-o-but-does-not-override-object-get

Comment: The idea is that if you define the `==` operator that you probably want to also override those methods to indicate that you want to sort and compare objects of that class on value rather than reference.  However you've defined the operators with different types which is in itself odd.  Really it looks like you should have defined explicit or implicit casts instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does Resharper want you to override `Equals`?

Consumers of your class are likely to assume `Equals` and `==` are semantically identical, but the C# language does not enforce this.

> Is Resharper's proposed implementation acceptable?

If you use Resharper's code, `Equals` and `==` will not be semantically identical, because your existing code allows instances of `CalculateToValue` to be equal to instances of `CalculateToMax`, whereas Resharper's code does not.

> How should I fix this?

1. Write a specification for exactly what should happen.  The goal is for you to actually know what your code is intended to do.  For example, the specification should explain under what circumstances an instance of `CalculateToMax` may be equal to an instance of `CalculateToValue`?
2. Write test cases for each piece of your specification.  [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022931/18192) provides a good starting point.
3. Write your code.

For an example of how to follow these steps, I recommend reading Eric Lippert's [Integer division that rounds up](https://ericlippert.com/2013/01/28/integer-division-that-rounds-up/) article.

> What else do I need to do?

Consider implenting [IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx).

> Why else should I know.

Consumers of your class are likely to assume `Equals`/`==` are reflexive (A==A), commutative (A==B ≡ B==A),  and transitive (A==B && B==C implies A==C).  Probably your implementation will be reflexive and transitive without much planning on your part, but making your implementation commutative isn't really possible, since `CalculateToMax` is an enum.

Usually equality implementations can be simplified by following a simple template and chaining together calls to the equality operations on your primitives.  Resharper is happy to auto-generate such code.  Unfortunately, in your case you are comparing classes to enumerations...which is really weird.

> Is there a way to make this easier?

Take a different approach entirely.  I recommend against using equality operators to compare enums to classes.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone please explain me why I get this warning?

Consider:

```
CalculateToValue ctv = whatever;
CalculateToMax ctm = whatever;
bool b1 = ctv.Equals(ctm);
bool b2 = ctv == ctm;
bool b3 = ctv.Equals((object)ctm);
```

Do you expect b1 b2 and b3 to have the same values or different values?

What results do you get with your original code?

What results do you get with your proposed fix?

Do you now believe that your proposed fix is wrong?  (You should.)

While you are looking at this code: do you notice anything deeply wrong about the implementation of `==`?  It says that two nulls are not equal to each other; is that right?  Seems wrong to me.

Comment: i am very sorry but i am not sure what comparision this code does.
I was just trying to fix the resharper warning. 

My porposed fix is the code suggested (generated) by resharper on top of all other existing code. Will adding this new code together with all other code, have any impact?

Comment: @App: Your question then is "*I want to remove a warning from incorrect code I don't understand by writing more incorrect code that I don't understand*."  You're doing this in the wrong order. **Start by deeply understanding the code**, and *then* decide how to fix the warning. The goal is not to remove the warning. **The goal is to make the code correct**.

Comment: @App: You say that the code is a "legacy" class that "works fine". Since it is chock full of bugs, by that I assume you mean a class that is (1) not adequately tested, and (2) that you don't understand.  If the code was adequately tested, then the bugs would have been fixed already, and if you understood the code, you'd see what tests were missing. Fix both those problems before you attempt to edit the code. When you write tests for this code you will quickly find that it has a lot of problems; once you know what the problems are and you understand the code, then fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. Appreciated. I will look deeper into the code.

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft guidelines, when you overload operator `"=="`, you should also override `Equals` and `GetHashcode`.

Check here for guidelines:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx(v=vs.100).aspx

Check overall recommendations for implementing `Equals`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx